# C code doesn't work

Tags: c

```
/*
 * main.c
 *
 *  Created on: Nov 30, 2012
 *      Author: mfb
 *
 *      Example input:
 *      5 5 2 2 0 0
 *  y0  . . . . .
 *  y1  a a a a .
 *  y2  . . . a .
 *  y3  . a a a .
 *  y4  . . . . .
 *
 *  x>  0 1 2 3 4
 *      I don't know why when I enter these to the program it comes to 4,4 and stops.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
int spx, spy, fx, fy, xsize, ysize;

char *inmap, *check;

int input(void) {
    scanf(" %d %d %d %d %d %d", &xsize, &ysize, &fx, &fy, &spx, &spy);
    inmap = (char *) malloc(xsize * ysize * sizeof(char));
    check = (char *) malloc(xsize * ysize * sizeof(char));

    int y;
    for (y = 0; y < xsize * ysize; y++)
        *(check + y) = 0;

    char o;
    for (y = 0; y < ysize * xsize; y++) {
        scanf(" %c", &o);
        if (o == '.')
            *(inmap + y) = 1;
        else
            *(inmap + y) = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int itaw(char *map, int fpx, int fpy) {
    if (*(check + fpy * xsize + fpx) == 1)
        return 0;
    else
        *(check + fpy * xsize + fpx) = 1;

    if (fpx >= xsize || fpy >= ysize || fpx < 0 || fpy < 0)
        return 0;

    if (*(map + fpy * xsize + fpx) == 0 || *(map + spy * xsize + spx) == 0)
        return 0;

    printf("(%d,%d)\n", fpx, fpy);
    if (fpx == spx && fpy == spy)
        return 1;

    return (itaw(map, fpx - 1, fpy) || itaw(map, fpx, fpy - 1)
            || itaw(map, fpx + 1, fpy) || itaw(map, fpx, fpy + 1));
}

int main(void) {
    input();
    int result = itaw(inmap, fx, fy);
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Above is a program that finds the way between two points. '.' means way and all of the other characters means a wall.
It mostly works but when I enter what I wrote above it returns 0.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in your debugger to see what's going on ?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a school project, so can I suggest the ever popular `project is due in a few hours, time for 9001 cout statements`?

Comment: Or a real debugger like @PaulR said ;)

Comment: @Saphrosit: No, [the homework tag is deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: @Windle: This is C code, so it would be 9001 printf statements ;)

Comment: it is not homework. I am 16 and interested in computers.

Comment: @netcoder Sorry, didn't know that! Thanks for the update, I removed the comment

Comment: My friend said you can't write something like that and I started writing. That's all.

Comment: An important part of learning to program is learning how to debug. If you haven't learned how to use a debugger yet then now would be a good time to start. And if you don't have a debugger then a good alternate debugging strategy is to insert strategic printf statements, as mentioned above.

Comment: Why is there a curly brace at the very top?

Comment: I don't know. I am new in this website. I don't know how to write code into my question.

Comment: @Borgleader Oh geez, and then I say screw it cause `cout` is "broken" lol

Comment: Well, this title is more than generic. Please consider making it a bit more descriptive/specific next time, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you don't do the bounds checking before accessing the variables. You must make sure that they are greater than 0 and less than max before accessing `check`. I think this is the correct version:

```
int itaw(char *map, int fpx, int fpy) {
    if (fpx >= xsize || fpy >= ysize || fpx < 0 || fpy < 0)
        return 0;
    if (*(check + fpy * xsize + fpx) == 1)
        return 0;
    else
        *(check + fpy * xsize + fpx) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. Does anybody know how to sign this question solved? I loved this website :D

Comment: Just click on the check mark symbol below the down-vote button.